# Why does slice() not work on an Array output from MongoDB find()?

Tags: mongodb, slice

In mongosh, I execute these commands:

```
[{title: '111'}, {title: '222'}].forEach(doc => console.log(doc.title))
[{title: '111'}, {title: '222'}].slice(0,1)

db.todos.find().forEach(doc => console.log(doc.title))
db.todos.find().slice(0,1)
```

and get this output:

[image]

Why does .slice() not work on the array coming from the MongoDB command db.todos.find()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The find() method returns a  FindCursor  that manages the results of
> your query. You can iterate through the matching documents using one
> of the following cursor methods:
>
> next() toArray() forEach()

Try:

```
db.todos.find().toArray().slice(0,1)
```

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/usage-examples/find/#find-multiple-documents